# why (-1) % vector::size() always returns 0

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote this code in C++.

```
vector<int> array = {1,2,3,4};
int i = (-1) % array.size();
```

Value i always has 0, but I want to get -1.
When I change the code into this with cast.

```
vector<int> array = {1,2,3,4};
int i = (-1) % (int)array.size();
```

Then i has -1.

I searched some attribute of vector::size() function in the internet.
However, I didn't understand.

Can anyone answer why this happens.
Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks for comment lgor.

Comment: [`(-1) % array.size()` is 3 for me](https://godbolt.org/z/3hefM5), not 0. The premise of your question is false.

Comment: It's better to post real code, I guess you actually had some other code that generated output of 0 but then made up this code for the question, not understanding the difference between this code and your real code

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice

Answer (score 1):

This is surely because `(-1) % array.size()` converts int `-1` to `size_t`. Thus becoming `0xFFFF...` depending on the exact type of `size_t`. Taking it modulo `4` results in `3`.

Not sure why you got `0`. Probably in your code size of the array was `3` despite what you wrote - in which case result would be `0`.

Edit: see the arithmetic conversion rules as to why the computation is done in `size_t` and not another type: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic